# WP_Query on custom field and order results

Tags: wp-query, loop, meta-query

I have the following WP_Query:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mcg_event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'  => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'event_status',
            'value' => 'archived',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'event_start_date',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',                     
            'order'     => 'ASC',
        )
    ),
);
```

I'm looking to do 2 things:

1. only fetch events that have an event_status of `archived`
2. order the results by `event_start_date`

I can do either of these queries separately with no problem but when I put them together as above the order makes no difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For the ordering you should use the orderby argument of the query. So it would go something like this:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'mcg_event',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'event_start_date',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'event_status',
            'value' => 'archived',
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with this and might help you with what you are looking for. The issue here is that we cannot include `key`, `order` and `orderby` in `meta_query`. But if you want to order you result posts based on key than you can pass the query arguments as below:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mcg_event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'event_status',
            'value' => 'archived',
        ),
    )
);
```